# my application crashing after successfully building

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, storage, android-applicationinfo

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.bedo.imagestorage, PID: 31127
>                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
>                         at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>                         at com.example.bedo.imagestorage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.bedo.imagestorage-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                         at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                         at com.example.bedo.imagestorage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq
>                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                 ... 16 more
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 31127 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Comment: have you added the firebase dependency in your gradle file?

Comment: yes i did 




implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'